# Tabbed view/ multiple google charts return error "e null"

Tags: html, css, charts, google-visualization

I have a tabbed style display on a wordpress page. Each tabbed needs to display a different pie chart.

code:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Level', ''],
      ['High Scool',     <?php echo $myrows->EduHsch;?>],
      ['Some College',      <?php echo $myrows->EduScoll;?>],
      ['Associate Degree',  <?php echo $myrows->EduAssoc;?>],
      ['Bachelor Degree', <?php echo $myrows->EduBach;?>],
      ['Graduate Degree',    <?php echo $myrows->Mardivor;?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Highest Level of Education',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('education'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

    function drawChart2() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Level', ''],
      ['Never Married',     <?php echo $myrows->MarNever;?>],
      ['Married',      <?php echo $myrows->MarMarr;?>],
      ['Seperated',  <?php echo $myrows->Marsep;?>],
      ['Widowed', <?php echo $myrows->MarWidow;?>],
      ['Divorced',    <?php echo $myrows->EduGrad;?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Marital Status',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('mar_chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

HTML:

```
     <div class="su-tabs su-tabs-style-default" data-active="1">
    <div class="su-tabs-nav" ><span class="" >Education</span><span class="" >Marital  Status</span><span class="" id="hh">Households</span><span class="">Commute</span></div>
    <div class="su-tabs-panes">
    <div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;display:block;" id="education">Education</div>
    <div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;display:block;"  id="mar_chart_div">Marital Status</div>
    <div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;display:block;"  id="house_chart_div">Households</div>
    <div class="su-tabs-pane su-clearfix"style="width: 500px; height: 500px;display:block;"  id="commute_chart_div">Commute</div>
    </div>
```

On page load it displays the chart for Education correctly but as soon as I choose any other tab it shows the **"e is null"**

Answer (score 0):

Drawing charts inside hidden divs (which is what most tab interfaces are) is known to cause problems in the Visualization API, though this error message is not what I would expect to see as a direct result of using tabs.  Solving this problem is likely to be an iterative process, so I'd like to start with a couple of different approaches to rule out some possible causes.

First, create this function:

```
function initialize () {
    drawChart();
    drawChart2();
}
```

and replace the `google.load` and `google.setOnLoadCallback` calls with this:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: initialize});
```

Reload the page with these changes.  Do you still see the error?

**[Edit - added generic code to help with tab issues]**

First, consolidating your code into a single draw function will probably help you here, as you have to coordinate the drawing of the two charts.  This code is an example for how to initialize your tabs after the charts draw:

```
function drawChart () {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Level', ''],
        ['High Scool', <?php echo $myrows->EduHsch;?>],
        ['Some College', <?php echo $myrows->EduScoll;?>],
        ['Associate Degree', <?php echo $myrows->EduAssoc;?>],
        ['Bachelor Degree', <?php echo $myrows->EduBach;?>],
        ['Graduate Degree', <?php echo $myrows->Mardivor;?>]
    ]);

    var options1 = {
        title: 'Highest Level of Education',
        is3D: true,
    };

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('education'));

    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Level', ''],
        ['Never Married', <?php echo $myrows->MarNever;?>],
        ['Married', <?php echo $myrows->MarMarr;?>],
        ['Seperated', <?php echo $myrows->Marsep;?>],
        ['Widowed', <?php echo $myrows->MarWidow;?>],
        ['Divorced', <?php echo $myrows->EduGrad;?>]
    ]);

    var options2 = {
        title: 'Marital Status',
        is3D: true,
    };

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('mar_chart_div'));

    var chartsReady = {
        chart1: false,
        chart2: false
    }

    function initTabs () {
        // initialize tab interface here
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {
        chartsReady.chart1 = true;
        if (chartsReady.chart2) {
            initTabs();
        }
    });
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'ready', function () {
        chartsReady.chart2 = true;
        if (chartsReady.chart1) {
            initTabs();
        }
    });

    chart1.draw(data1, options1);
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
```

If instead you want to draw each chart when it's container tab is first opened, then you want something like this instead:

```
function drawChart () {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Level', ''],
        ['High Scool', <?php echo $myrows->EduHsch;?>],
        ['Some College', <?php echo $myrows->EduScoll;?>],
        ['Associate Degree', <?php echo $myrows->EduAssoc;?>],
        ['Bachelor Degree', <?php echo $myrows->EduBach;?>],
        ['Graduate Degree', <?php echo $myrows->Mardivor;?>]
    ]);

    var options1 = {
        title: 'Highest Level of Education',
        is3D: true,
    };

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('education'));

    function tab1Open () {
        chart1.draw(data1, options1);
    }

    // hook up an event handler on your tabs that calls tab1Open when the education tab is opened

    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Level', ''],
        ['Never Married', <?php echo $myrows->MarNever;?>],
        ['Married', <?php echo $myrows->MarMarr;?>],
        ['Seperated', <?php echo $myrows->Marsep;?>],
        ['Widowed', <?php echo $myrows->MarWidow;?>],
        ['Divorced', <?php echo $myrows->EduGrad;?>]
    ]);

    var options2 = {
        title: 'Marital Status',
        is3D: true,
    };

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('mar_chart_div'));

    function tab2Open () {
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
    }

    // hook up an event handler on your tabs that calls tab2Open when the mar_chart_div tab is opened
}
```

Both of these concepts can be extended to include an arbitrary number of charts and tabs.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it seems to do the trick yesterday but now it says -

Cannot read property 'length' of null

Can you exmplain how to do with this. Do the divs need to not be in "display:none"? If I don't do that then it shows are charts together but I don't want. It should display the chart only when clicked on the specific tab

Comment: The next part is to tackle the drawing.  You have two basic options: either draw all charts before initializing your tabs, or draw each chart the first time it's container tab is opened.

Comment: The code depends on the library you use for your tabs.  I'll add some generic code that you can use as a guideline.